# HTML5 Audio player as post header in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I was trying to figure out how I can use html5 audio player as post header for my website. e.g where you would usually see a title of post I want to have audio player with post related song. I cant figure out how such feature can be achieved, is there a way to edit post page in Wordpress dashboard in order to enable such functionality or what other ways are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by modifying the theme.

Use custom fields to define the src of your audio file and insert your audio player tags next to title of the post in your loop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: Oh I didn't know about these custom fields, yea this makes it a lot easier thnx